# Editable plots in PowerPoint from python: equivalent of officer and rvg

Tags: python, r, plot, graphics, powerpoint

I am using the `officer` and `rvg` packages to get plots from R into MS PowerPoint as editable vector graphics. Reproducible example below.

I am looking for a way to implement an equivalent solution with python, preferably using `matplotlib`. The critical part is not the creation of slides from the IDE but rather the editable vector graphics part, i.e. plots should end up in PowerPoint as grouped objects comprised of a range of simple powerpoint geometries such as lines, squares, and text fields.

R example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(officer)
library(rvg)

# Get some data and make a plot
ggp <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(clarity) %>%
  summarise(price = mean(price)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = clarity, y = price, fill = clarity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', colour = 'black')

# Create a new powerpoint document
doc <- read_pptx()
doc <- add_slide(doc, 'Title and Content', 'Office Theme')
# Add the plot 
doc <- ph_with_vg(doc, ggobj = ggp, type = 'body')  

# Write the document to a file
print(doc, target = 'plots.pptx')
```

The resulting chart is completely editable:

[image]

Comment: I don't know any python packages that can achieve this. But why do you prefer a fake chart made of ppt primitives over a real ppt chart?

Comment: "real" ppt charts offer only a limited range of possible plots and don't work well on large amounts of data. I prefer to create my plots in R or python and then export them for customers. However, often customers (business stakeholders, project managers, or clients) want small changes afterwards (change a colour or a font). That means reloading the data which can be time consuming and expensive. The ability to modify the plots "after the fact" in powerpoint takes care of that.

Comment: Using something like https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/charts.html you have all the above advantages: you can create the plot in python and then export to PPT, after the export you can change the colour or the font. The only difference is, that instead of fake, primitive-based chart, you have an actual Powerpoint chart in your slides.

Comment: Thanks @r4ch. That is a solution for some users but for me standard power point figures don't cut it for most of my use cases. Good to have the link in here nonetheless!

Comment: Looks like this function is now defunct. @JanLauGe can you update with a reproducible example. > doc <- ph_with_vg(doc, ggobj = ggp, type = 'body')  
Error: 'ph_with_vg' is defunct.
Use 'officer::ph_with' instead.
See help("Defunct")

Comment: @JanLauGe Hi, I have a question that is related to yours. Currently, I am in front of the task to automate report generation (preferably PowerPoint) with the data I get from the numerical analysis software (ABAQUS), which uses Python for scripting. What package have you found as a good solution for "I am using the ```officer``` and ```rvg``` packages to get plots from R into MS PowerPoint" in Python?

Comment: Hi @Mike, seems there is no solution directly comparable to the R workflow but see Koen's answer below as a starting point for creating your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 2019 version of MS office you can add `svg` files as images and then ungroup them to make them editable. See 'Convert an SVG image to an Office shape' on this [MS page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-office-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c). In my personal experience, this is however *neither very stable nor complete*.

Another way, which is *more stable and complete although still not perfect*, is importing it in powerpoint as `emf` file, which is also a vector-format. Old version of matplotlib could export to this format. For newer version, I export as `svg` and then use `inkscape --file "input.svg" --export-emf "output.emf"` to convert to `emf`, which I then load in powerpoint. Ungrouping the object again allows you to edit, if everything works well.